# Websharper can't deserialize union type

Tags: f#, websharper

I have the following client code:

```
|>! OnClick (fun _ _ -> Server.CreateBug input.Value |> Server.SendCommand)
```

Here's the type and server code:

```
type Command =
    | CreateBug of string
    | Query of Query * AsyncReplyChannel<string>

[<Rpc>]
let SendCommand cmd =
    dispatcher.Post cmd
```

The client can serialize this to: [{"$":0,"$0":"test"}]

But then I get the following log error when debugging:

> WebSharper.Web Error: 0 : Failed to execute a remote call. Failed to get JSON deserializer for: ClientReferral.Server+Command[]
>
> WebSharper Error: 0 : Failed to execute a remote call. Failed to get JSON deserializer for: ClientReferral.Server+Command[]

This code is rather trivial and there doesn't seem to be anything indicating it wouldn't work in the WebSharper manual. I even remember using it like that, so I don't know what's wrong.

Edit:
This is the definition of Query:

```
type Query =
    | GetBugs
    | GetBugInfo of int
```

Comment: Is `Query of Query` supposed to be `Query of Command`?

Comment: Basically, I want to send Commands or Queries to the server, Queries would typically be wrapped into a command with the ReplyChannel and dispatched to an agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fact that the error is happening at runtime and not at compile time is definitely a bug, I will try to reproduce and fix on Monday.

Technically, since AsyncReplyChannel<'T> does not have a default constructor WebSharper cannot construct a deserializer for it.

Looking at the higher level, I cannot understand your intent. Why send a function-isomorphic type over RPC?

Moreover, this:

```
|>! OnClick (fun _ _ -> Server.CreateBug input.Value |> Server.SendCommand)
```

This looks to me like an attempt to construct an object on the server, then gratuitously send it to the client and back, and then do something with it - is this right? I assume Server.* functions execute on the server. If so, it must be refactored to a single call:

```
|>! OnClick (fun _ _ -> Server.SendBugCommand input.Value)

[<Rpc>]
let SendBugCommand x =
    CreateBug x
    |> SendCommand
```

Comment: Ok removing the AsyncReplyChannel fixed the problem thank you.

Comment: I understand the intent is misleading... Server.CreateBug isn't a server side function, rather the Server.Command.CreateBug union type. I also verified that the construction was done on the client side as such there's no additional round trip.

My intent is to have the client be able to send various types of commands to the server which I serialize to preserve history and execute the related code.

I don't understand the bits about 'Why send a function-isomorphic...' In which way is invoking a server side method directly better than sending the various command to the one entry point?

Comment: Commands are fine. The fun starts when closures are being sent. What confused me is that you can wrap a closure in AsyncReplyChannel. WebSharper currently will not allow to send closures over RPC in either direction, but in a system that does it, it still is unclear to me what the semantics and implementation of it should be. Anyway, good luck with what you are doing!

Comment: Ok great... I switched the query agent to take a tuple of Query and AsyncReplyChannel instead of including it in my union. This provides me better separation for my commands and queries, I like that.